# Initialising array with unknown size in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int average(int array []);

int main () {

int num_array[];


int x = 0;

  while(num_array[x] != -1){

     printf("Enter a number\n");
     scanf("%d",&num_array[x]);

     x++;

  }

  printf("%d\n", average(num_array));

  return 0;
}



int average(int array[]){

  int i;
  int total_size = (int)sizeof(array);
  int sum = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < total_size; i++){

    sum = sum + array[i];

  }

  return sum/total_size;

}
```

But i get an error at compile time, because i'm not initialising the array. However i can't do it, since i don't know it's size.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Use `malloc()` and `realloc()`.

Comment: @ForceBru as they said, you need to use `malloc()` with a pointer to an array. `int* num_array;` then use that pointer in `malloc()`

Comment: In order to avoid `realloc`, first ask for the user about the array size. In order to avoid `malloc`, set the array's maximum size and allocate it statically.

Comment: @DylanLawrence can you show me in an example ?

Comment: `int* num_array; num_array = (int*) malloc(size+1);` You should probably check if `malloc()` returns null, but this is the basic setup.

Comment: @Lundin The point is that it's much easier to google it rather than write a question on SO.. So laziness isn't an excuse

Comment: @DylanLawrence http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @EugeneSh. Laziness as in no research effort.

Comment: @Lundin if you do not want to provide any help, just vote the question down and make pointless observations, please go somewhere else.

Comment: @laker001 Oh but I helped by doing the research for you, by finding one of many duplicates to the question. Read away!

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare an array like

```
int num_array[];
```

in C except when it is a parameter of a function. You must have to specify the size.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a surprisingly tricky problem in C unless you're using an array library. What you're actually talking about is a growable array. For what you're trying to do, you start with an initial size, say 10, using `malloc()` and as the inputs grow, you have to `realloc()` the array to a larger size. Generally, you double the size of the array every time the limit is hit. If you're a beginning C programmer, this is probably too much to take on. I would set a fixed limit, and enforce it by not accepting any more input after the limit is hit. Given that you can comfortably allocate 1000's of `int`s and a human won't want to type that much, you can easily make a practical limit ahead of time and declare the array as such:

```
int num_array[1000];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the size of the array here: `int num_array[];`.

If you are working with a structure of unknown size, you could:

- Ask the user how many numbers are going to be entered (not really practical, but might suffice if your case is a trivial one).
- Initialize it with a default size, say 10 and then if you need, create larger arrays and copying your current data to the new one.
- Or else, you use a linked list like data structure and create new elements as you go along, thus allowing your list to grow as much as you need it to be.